# Using generics as method parameter Java

Tags: java, generics, interface, overriding, abstract-class

I have an interface :

```
    public interface DDLOperation <T extends Artifact> {

    public void alter(T artifact);

    public void create(T artifact);

    public void drop(T artifact);

}
```

I also have an abstract class implementing that interface :

```
    public abstract class AbstractDDLOperation <T extends Artifact> implements DDLOperation {

    @Override
    public abstract void alter(T artifact);

    @Override
    public abstract void create(T artifact);

    @Override
    public abstract void drop(T artifact);

    public void processChildElement(Element childElement) {
        Artifact artifact = createArtifact(childElement);
        alter(artifact);
    }
}
```

Eclipse gives this error in AbstractDDLOperation class : *The method alter(T) of type AbstractDDLOperation must override or implement a supertype method*

I want all subclasses implementing AbstractDDLOperation to pass different type of parameters, all extending from Artifact class to the methods alter, create and drop.

Can anyone give a suggestion about the issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class should implement `DDLOperation<T>`, not the raw `DDLOperation`.

It should be:

```
public abstract class AbstractDDLOperation <T extends Artifact> implements DDLOperation<T>
```

Otherwise, your abstract class's methods don't override or implement any of the super type (interface) methods, so the `@Override` annotation is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks it solved the problem, but I have another issue : when i call `alter(artifact)` in abstract class it gives another error : _The method alter(T) in the type AbstractDDLOperation<T> is not applicable for the arguments (Artifact)_ . Any suggestions about this one?

Comment: @TuncerTunçer please edit your question to include that code that causes this error.

Comment: This is because you defined the interface to accept only T ( which happens to implement Artifact ), not any class that implements Artifact

Comment: @TuncerT. `alter` accepts an argument of type T, not any Artifact. If you instantiated your class (or actually some concrete sub-class of your abstract class) with `new ConcreteDDLOperation<SomeArtifact>()`, you'll only be able to pass `SomeArtifact` instances to `alter()`. Perhaps your `createArtifact(childElement)` method should be changed to return `T` (if possible).

Comment: @GonenI Artifact is only a super class for other types of artifacts, like Index, Table and etc. So if I understand correct, you say that, parameter to the method alter(artifact) should be a subclass, not a superclass. What happens if I cast the argument to Artifact?

Comment: See Eran's comment above. You have two choices. Send an actual T to the method, or change the interface to accept Artifact instead of <T extends Artifact>.  As an analogy, you can think of it this way: you would not want a List<Double> to have an alter function which accepts any Number (e.g. Integer) , even though Double and Integer both extend Number.

Comment: @Eran thanks again. I think that is exactly what I should do.